# Slice, combine, and map fiscal year dates to calendar year dates to new column

Tags: python, pandas, date, dictionary

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code     Stage_Code
10225003                      2
8225003                       1
8225004                       3
8225005                       4
```

It is part of a much larger dataset that I need to be able to filter by month and year.  I need to pull the fiscal year from the first two digits for values larger than 9999999 in the Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code column, and the first digit for values less than or equal to 9999999.  That value needs to be added to "20" to produce a year i.e. "20" + "8" = 2008 | "20" + "10" = 2010.

That year "2008, 2010" needs to be combined with the stage code value (1-12) to produce a month/year, i.e. 02/2010.

The date 02/2010 then needs to converted from fiscal year date to calendar year date, i.e. Fiscal Year Date : 02/2010 = Calendar Year date: 08/2009.  The resulting date needs to be presented in a new column.  The resulting df would end up looking like this:

```
Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code     Stage_Code     Date
10225003                      2              08/2009
8225003                       1              07/2007
8225004                       3              09/2007
8225005                       4              10/2007
```

I am new to pandas and python and could use some help.  I am beginning with this:

```
Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code   Stage_Code  CY_Month    Fiscal_Year
    0   10225003                 2           8.0        10
    1   8225003                  1           7.0        82
    2   8225003                  1           7.0        82
    3   8225003                  1           7.0        82
    4   8225003                  1           7.0        82
```

I used .map and .str methods to produce this df, but have not been able to figure out how to get the FY's right, for fy 2008-2009.

Comment: updated for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below code, I'll assume `Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code` is an integer. If it's a string you can convert it or slice it like this: `df['Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code'].str[:-6]`. More explanations in comments alongside the code.

That should work as long as you don't have to deal with empty values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

fiscal_month_offset = 6

input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[10225003, 2],
    [8225003, 1],
    [8225004, 3],
    [8225005, 4]],
    columns=['Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code', 'Stage_Code'])

# make a copy of input dataframe to avoid modifying it
df = input_df.copy()

# numpy will help us with numeric operations on large collections
df['fiscal_year'] = 2000 + np.floor_divide(df['Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code'], 1000000)

# loop with `apply` to create `date` objects from available columns
# day is a required field in date, so we'll just use 1
df['fiscal_date'] = df.apply(lambda row: date(row['fiscal_year'], row['Stage_Code'], 1), axis=1)

df['calendar_date'] = df['fiscal_date'] - relativedelta(months=fiscal_month_offset)
# by default python dates will be saved as Object type in pandas. You can verify with `df.info()`
# to use clever things pandas can do with dates we need co convert it
df['calendar_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calendar_date'])

# I would just keep date as datetime type so I could access year and month
# but to create same representation as in question, let's format it as string
df['Date'] = df['calendar_date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')

# copy important columns into output dataframe
output_df = df[['Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code', 'Stage_Code', 'Date']].copy()
print(output_df)
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I found a zero value for Stage Code and Shortcut Dimension 4 Code. Any ideas how to skip over a zero value?  Or will I have to drop it to complete running the function?

Comment: `df = input_df.query('Shortcut_Dimension_4_Code != 0 and Stage_Code != 0')` would give you a filtered dataframe to work with.